# Why using Scopes and Singleton annotations in Dagger2 with kotlin causes error while compiling?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp, dagger-2

The App is working fine unless i add @MainScope or @Singleton annotation before some "provides" method, then i am getting gradle build error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   Internal compiler error. See log for more details

The logs contains this:

> Build timestamps: Local: 1508577084874, Device: 1508577084874 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:34,358 [ 216576]   INFO - ools.idea.fd.InstantRunBuilder - BuildCause: FIRST_INSTALLATION_TO_DEVICE, BuildMode: FULL 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:34,359 [ 216577]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:34,377 [ 216595]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:34,408 [ 216626]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\prebuilts\tools\common\offline-m2' 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:34,408 [ 216626]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.api=25, -Pandroid.injected.build.density=560dpi, -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=x86, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.name=debug, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.project=:app, -Pandroid.optional.compilation=INSTANT_DEV,FULL_APK, -Pandroid.injected.coldswap.mode=MULTIAPK] 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:34,420 [ 216638]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --configure-on-demand -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.api=25 -Pandroid.injected.build.density=560dpi -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=x86 -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.name=debug -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.project=:app -Pandroid.optional.compilation=INSTANT_DEV,FULL_APK -Pandroid.injected.coldswap.mode=MULTIAPK 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:36,975 [ 219193]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList) 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:171)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:143)
>       at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.getSimpleMessageConstructor(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createNewMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:272)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:250)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage$default(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:244)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelperKt.parse(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:66)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParser.parse(KotlinOutputParser.java:28)
>       at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.ToolOutputParser.parseToolOutput(ToolOutputParser.java:86)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.output.parser.BuildOutputParser.parseGradleOutput(BuildOutputParser.java:43)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor$GradleTasksExecutorImpl.lambda$collectMessages$5(GradleTasksExecutor.java:517)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:342)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2017-10-21 11:18:36,981 [ 219199]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - Exception from KotlinOutputParser 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:36,983 [ 219201]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList) 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:171)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:143)
>       at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.getSimpleMessageConstructor(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createNewMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:272)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:250)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage$default(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:244)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelperKt.parse(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:41)
>       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParser.parse(KotlinOutputParser.java:28)
>       at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.ToolOutputParser.parseToolOutput(ToolOutputParser.java:86)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.output.parser.BuildOutputParser.parseGradleOutput(BuildOutputParser.java:43)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor$GradleTasksExecutorImpl.lambda$collectMessages$5(GradleTasksExecutor.java:517)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:342)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2017-10-21 11:18:36,983 [ 219201]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - Exception from KotlinOutputParser 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:37,092 [ 219310]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:37,108 [ 219326]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, success = false 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:37,195 [ 219413]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 8ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:37,334 [ 219552]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 138ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:37,339 [ 219557]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 8 files to update 
>   2017-10-21 11:18:37,556 [ 219774]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 217ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok

And here is my module:

```
@Module
class MainModule(val activity: Activity) {

@Provides
fun providesContext(): Context = activity.baseContext

@Provides
fun providesActivity(): Activity = activity

@Provides
@MainScope
fun providesView(activity: Activity): MainActivityView = MainActivityView(activity)

@Provides
@MainScope
fun providesPresenter(view: MainActivityView): MainPresenter = MainPresenter(view)}
```

MainScope:

```
    import javax.inject.Qualifier
import javax.inject.Scope

@Scope
annotation class MainScope
```

EDIT

MainComponent:

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(MainModule::class), dependencies = 
arrayOf(ApplicationComponent::class))
public interface MainComponent{
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

EDIT 2:
[Here is whole project on github](https://github.com/KubenQPL/NewSeriesApp)

Comment: Please read your error log carefully and include only the relevant parts in your question. If this is a Dagger error, there is a clear error message by Dagger somewhere, which you missed.

Comment: Where is your component code?

Comment: I don't know what i should be looking for in this logs and can't find any dagger debug logs.
@EpicPandaForce Added.
I am trying make app with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ8AtBGLhmM

Comment: Ah it's clearly because `@AppScope` is marked as qualifier instead of scope (although it is replaced by @Singleton anyways) and that your components aren't marked with their scope (@Singleton on AppComponent and @MainScope on MainComponent)